# sql update one to many using spring jpa (foreign key null)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

Im working with **spring boot**, **java 11** and **jpa**.

I have 2 tables, entry and entry_names. I want to update both an entry, and its subsequent many to one relationship in the second table(entry_names).

**The problem:**
Entry_id field is always null, so it creates new entries in Entry_names instead of updating them. What am i doing wrong? This is my most up-to-date code:

**Tables:**

```
+-------+
| Entry |
+-------+
| id    | pk:id
| title |
| text  |
+-------+

+-----------+
|entry_names| 
+-----------+
| id        | pk: id 
| name      | fk: entry_id -> entry(id)
| entry_id  |
+-----------+
```

These are the entities:

**Entry:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entry")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
    
    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "entry",         
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<EntryNames> names;
}
```

**Entry_names**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entry_names")
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntryNames {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entry_id")
    private Entry entry;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Code:**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean update(EntryDto dto) {
    
    try {
        Optional<Entry> findEntry = dao.findById(entry.getId());
        if (findEntry.isPresent()) {
            Entry entry = findEntry.get();
            
            Set<EntryNames> entryNames = new HashSet<>();
            entry.getName().forEach(entryNames -> entryNames.add(new EntryName(entryName)));
            entryNames.forEach(entryName -> entryName.setId(entry.getId()));
            entry.setName(entryNames);
            dao.save(entry);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("ERROR: {}", exception.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

(edited to remove assignment, still same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting names with new HashSet<>(); which will overwrite the values.

Change to:

```
  private Set<EntryNames> names ;
```

Aslo add this in update method

```
 entrynames.setEntry(entry)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i remove that assignment i get a nullpointer when setting names in the entry. Even if i assign it inside the update method of the service, the entry_id is still null.

Comment: Remove new hashset from class definition , not the update method.

Comment: thats what i meant, i removed the new HashSet, and got a null pointer.

Comment: Then i moved it to update method, with the same result(null id)

Comment: do private Long Id = 0L; in both the class definitions should remove null pointer. If the issue still persists, then share more code.

Comment: the nullpointer with this solution is names field in Entry, not id. Id must not be set, as it is handled by the autoincrement

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what you mean, as setting id has nothing to do with the value of entry_id extracted from the table. The problem is still the same. Id must not be set, as its set automatically.

Comment: If names field is null that means there is no corresponding row in the other table. Then you should create new object And set it directly. If you want to update your entry the don't create new object, instead just use your setter to update values. As orm maps objects to its corresponding rows in DB.

Comment: Entry_id is null, not names :) Also, im not creating a new object. Im getting it and setting it and saving the modified object, as you say. Thats my problem :) It does not work.

Comment: Try setting entrynames.setEntry(entry).

Comment: I can see the issue now you are overwriting I'd of entryname table instead of entry_id with this line entryName.setId(entry.getId())) in entryNames.forEach(entryName -> entryName.setId(entry.getId()));

Comment: entrynames.setEntry(entry) was the solution. thank you very much :)